# Vector field flux from the box

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to calculate vector field:

$$\mathbf{F} = ({3\cdot x^3\cdot y^2+3})\mathbf{i}+({\frac{y^2+2\cdot x}{3}})\mathbf{j}+({3\cdot y\cdot z^3+3})\mathbf{k}$$

flux from the box which coordinates are $(0,1,0)$ and $(2,2,1)$ and the faces are parallel to the coordinate planes.

So

$$\iiint_V\frac{\delta F_x}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta F_y}{\delta y}+\frac{\delta F_z}{\delta z}\,dV=\int_0^2\int_1^2\int_0^19x^2y+\frac{2y}{3}+9z^2y\,dx\,dy\,dz=52$$

$52$ is not correct answer. I don't know where I have done mistake.

Comment: check the integrand of your iterated integral.

Comment: The first integration is with respect to $z$ which has limit $0,1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\iiint_V\frac{\delta F_x}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta F_y}{\delta y}+\frac{\delta F_z}{\delta z}\,dV=\int_0^2\int_1^2\int_0^1 \color{green}{9x^2y^2}+\frac{2y}{3}+9z^2y\color{red}{\,dz}\,dy\color{red}{\,dx}=67$$